# How to make container div resize with changes on a child div?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a button inside a side-column that will show some text if clicked, however I noticed that text overflows the original container div:

https://jsfiddle.net/czjub804/10/

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: auto;
  background-color:red;
}

.main-column {
  margin-left: 8vw;
  background-color:blue;
}

.side-column {
  margin: 4vw auto;
  align-content: flex-start;
  width: 20vw;
  height: auto;
  background-color:purple;
}

.about-author-text {
  font-family: "Merriweather";
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 2;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 0;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: font-size 0.5s ease-in-out;
  color: var(--light-text-color);
}

.visible {
  visibility: visible;
  max-height: auto;
  width: inherit;
  line-height: 2;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding: 0;
}
```

How can I make the .columns div (red background) expand its height when the text is visible?

Comment: `height: 0` set in your `.about-author-text class` is the reason for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `height: 0` set on the class `.about-author-text`.
It doesn't really make sense to have the container's height set to 0.

Answer (score 1):

I've changed your css class for you

```
.about-author-text {
  font-family: "Merriweather";
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 2;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: font-size 0.5s ease-in-out;
  color: var(--light-text-color);
}
```

I've removed the height property.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `height` property from the `.about-author-text` class.

```js
const text = document.getElementById("about-text")

function showText() {
 text.classList.toggle("visible")
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: auto;
  background-color:red;
}

.main-column {
  margin-left: 8vw;
  background-color:blue;
}

.side-column {
  margin: 4vw auto;
  align-content: flex-start;
  width: 20vw;
  height: auto;
  background-color:purple;
}

.about-author-text {
  font-family: "Merriweather";
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 2;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: font-size 0.5s ease-in-out;
  color: var(--light-text-color);
}

.visible {
  visibility: visible;
  max-height: auto;
  width: inherit;
  line-height: 2;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding: 0;
}

.about-author-text p:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="main-column">
helllo
</div>
<div class="side-column">
<button onclick="showText()">
About
</button>
<div id="about-text" class="about-author-text">
             <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer auctor nec libero sit amet gravida. Maecenas blandit pulvinar nulla, et porta purus ultrices vel. Curabitur vestibulum accumsan nulla, a ullamcorper arcu tempor molestie. Nulla vitae sollicitudin sem. Suspendisse hendrerit, purus sed congue fringilla, ex mauris porta metus, imperdiet congue elit dolor et mauris. Aliquam ut turpis pretium, feugiat libero nec, finibus mi. Sed ac sagittis tortor. Cras quis tellus vel ligula vehicula tristique in ac erat. Donec mollis hendrerit elit, vel tempor nulla ornare sed.

Nullam at congue ex. Etiam velit libero, dictum in tristique non, pulvinar non orci. Nam nibh diam, porttitor et bibendum at, molestie ut metus. Praesent congue tellus sit amet elit venenatis feugiat. Nam vitae erat elit. Integer fermentum magna ut tempus accumsan. Cras vitae tortor vehicula, bibendum nulla sit amet, dignissim massa. Nunc a lorem egestas, fermentum purus in, lacinia odio. Etiam scelerisque risus sit amet magna consequat, pharetra scelerisque elit egestas. Pellentesque vitae blandit lectus, at rhoncus libero. Vivamus hendrerit tellus dolor, facilisis fringilla lorem viverra non. Integer eros est, luctus ut orci id, rutrum porta risus. Nam sollicitudin tempor nunc ut mollis. 
             </p>
            </div>
</div>
</div>
```